# jQuery - can anybody help me...?

Tags: jquery, append

I'm using this code for append some code using jQuery but it won't work.

```
$('#'+DivId).append($(maincontent).fadeIn('slow'));
```

but if I use this then it works perfectly

```
$('#'+DivId).html(maincontent);
```

Does anybody know what is the problem with `append()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
$("#your_div").fadeIn('slow');
$('#'+DivId).append(maincontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. It may be that you need to run inside a `$(document).ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maincontent = "<p>Just some text to test...</p>";
    $("#test").append($(maincontent).fadeIn('slow'));
});
```

You can see the above code running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/TEw8F/).